# NextAuth Get Session in App Router API Route

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13, next-auth, app-router

I'm using NextAuth and Next.js's App Router. I've created an API route in my /app/api folder. However, I am unable to retrieve the session corresponding to the request.

Here is my API route, which I am calling with the `get(url)` method:

```
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
    const session = await getServerSession(req);

    console.log(session);

    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 });
}
```

However, when this runs, I get the following error on the server:

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Invalid Compact JWE {
  message: 'Invalid Compact JWE',
  stack: 'JWEInvalid: Invalid Compact JWE\n' +
    '    at compactDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:18:15)\n' +
    '    at jwtDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:10:61)\n' +
    '    at Object.decode (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:44:52)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:25:34)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:161:37)\n' +
    '    at async getServerSession (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:126:21)\n' +
    '    at async GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/newwatchlist/route.ts:11:21)\n' +
    '    at async D:\\Coding Projects\\market-pulse\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:61856',
  name: 'JWEInvalid'
}
```

`session` is then null.

I don't have access to a response object to pass the normal `getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)` method (as far as I know).

How do I get the session corresponding to the HTTP request with Next's new API routes?

Note: I am using the MongoDB adapter.

**Update:** I also tried taking `res: NextApiResponse` as a parameter and then fetching the session with `const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);`. However, this results in `TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just need to pass authOptions and neither res nor req:
`const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);`

Then, my whole function looks like this:

```
export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest) {
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);  
    console.log(session);
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Unauthorized" }, { status: 401 }; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you did not pass jwt related information to `getServerSession`

```
// you just passed req
// you have to define authOptions
const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
```

Comment: I updated my code to take res as a parameter and pass res and authOptions. However, I get TypeError: res.getHeader is not a function.

Comment: if `res:NextResponse`, you should have `res.headers.get()`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pass the authOptions into the getServerSession(authOptions) and In order to getServerSession(authOptions) in API Route,

1. in Server Component:
   You need to pass the Cookie in requests headers when fetching the data because server component does not have access to browser cookie like client component

```js
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/me`, {
    headers: headers()
  });
  return res.json();
};
```

2. in Client Component: You already have the cookie when making request

```js
const getUser = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/users/me`);
  return res.json();
};
```